# Parse data returned from j.mp

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, json, bit.ly

I'm currently writing an iPhone application, that posts a long url to j.mp (bit.ly). It is fully working and posts the long url successfully. But when I want to copy the returned data into an UITextView, I just get some JSON Data. Now my question: How can I parse this data, so that I only have the shortened url?

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of JSON parsers out there that you can use. One that I've worked with is [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON) which performed great.